# Interrupt a python script

Tags: python

How interrupt this Code at start in raspberry.

The problem is that it starts automatically.

I have put it in /etc/profile

I want to know how i can escape from that at the beginning or is it not possible?

```
from picamera import PiCamera

import time

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()

while(1):

    camera.capture("/home/pi/test.png")

camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: What means *interrupt* here? Wait for some event? Keyboard event? Network event? File system event? Or in the opposite side process normally unless some event (here again keyboard, file system, etc.)?

Comment: Keyboard event i describe it an answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of the `while` loop and use `time.sleep()`

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
# Camera warm-up time
sleep(2)
camera.capture('/home/pi/test.png')
```

[PiCamera Docs](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html)

Comment: The problem is it starts automatically i have put it in /etc/profile so i want to know how i can escape from that at the beginning or is it not possible

Comment: @Tikorz You have added it to /etc/profile so it executes every time a user logs in but you don't want it to be executed? Why add it to /etc/profile then?

Comment: No it is starting normal then the camera starts over the full screen so now i want to escape it with a combination of keys or something like that .

Comment: I can´t stop it :) if i want to stop it i must loose the contact from the camera

Answer (score 0):

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time

camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()

while(1):
    try:
        camera.capture("/home/pi/test.png")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
camera.stop_preview()
```

stop it with CTRL+C

Comment: it does nothing if i hit CTRL+C at autostart :/ and another problem is in this code it zooms in and out every time

Comment: in Desktop mode there is no problem there is everything correct.